# How to automate scroll in dialog box using selenium java

Tags: java, css, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate Instagram website, when I click followers link it opens a dialog box with users to follow. When I try to scroll that dialog box it is scrolling the main page but not the followers dialog box. How to achieve this?

I tried with the code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.pbNvD.fPMEg.HYpXt"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)",element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try scroll top in the below two ways :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.pbNvD.fPMEg.HYpXt"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop(100)",element);
```

or

```
js.executeScript("$('div.pbNvD.fPMEg.HYpXt').scrollTop(100)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code to scroll modal dialog down:

```
// Wait for modal
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("document-content")));
// Select last child of content div
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='document-content']/*[last()]")); 
// Scroll to last child node
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```